# virtualenv easy_install gcc error

Tags: virtualenv

We just got a new server at work, of which I do not have root access to.
I'm running virtualenv and trying to install MySQL-python and python-ldap but keep getting a gcc error.

I've tried using pip with the same results.

Here's a dump from the terminal as I'm trying to install:

http://pastebin.com/vJY6yeaZ

Any direction would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It seems that MySQL-python is already install.

python-ldap requires the OpenLDAP libraries to be installed first, once I install them it works fine.

Thanks,
Jeremy